# How do I break this complex number equation down so I can solve it?

Tags: complex-numbers

> Solve the equation and show all values $\left(\dfrac{x-4i}{2i}\right)^3 = i$

I was attempting questions such as $x^4 + 4x^2 +16=0$ which will involve complex numbers, then I encounter this question where the equation is already expressed in a complex number format. How do I go about breaking apart the expression and solving it? My mind blanked when I see this expression

Comment: Take cube roots on both sides. This will give three possible values on the right. Do you know how to find the cube roots of a complex number?

Comment: @user170231 I'm pretty sure I did not learn that

Comment: I would recommend looking over [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#Complex_roots) for a start

Comment: Hi! If you're not comfortable with taking cube roots of a complex number, you've probably missed something (if you are taking a course, for example), or else you've moved ahead in self-study rather too far. Can you clarify? Where did you see this question?

Comment: You can solve this without knowing how to take complex cube roots. For simplicity, let $z=x-4i$, so that the equation becomes $z^3-8=0$. This is a difference of cubes: $z^3-8 = (z-2)(z^2+2z+4)$. The first factor gives you $z=2$; now use the quadratic formula on the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the equation as

$$\left(\frac{x-4i}{2i}\right)^3 = \frac{(x-4i)^3}{8i^3} = i \iff (x-4i)^3 = 8i^4 = 8$$

In polar form, $8=8e^{i0}$. Taking the cube root, we get

$$\sqrt[3]{8}\,e^{i(0+2\pi k)/3} = 2e^{i\,2k\pi/3}$$

where $k\in\{0,1,2\}$. That is,

$$z^3 = 8 \implies z = \begin{cases} 2e^{i0} = 2 & \text{if } k = 0 \\ 2e^{i\,2\pi/3} = -1 + i\sqrt3 & \text{if } k = 1 \\ 2e^{i\,4\pi/3} = -1 - i\,\sqrt3 & \text{if } k = 2 \end{cases}$$